# How to stop execution in Svelte?

Tags: javascript, typescript, server, svelte, sveltekit

For example, in PHP it is possible to stop execution using `exit();`.

How do I simply stop the script from continuing?

Not shutting down the server, but ending the request and showing a blank message on the screen, like:

`Script ended abruptly.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [call `error`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/errors), which will show the `+error.svelte` page.

To signal that this was due to some interruption, you can pass something via the second argument and use that information in the component via `$page.error` (e.g. a code to resolve or a message to show directly).